# EXECUTE <query-string> USING value1... chokes on first substitution-placeholder ($1)

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.2

The following code fails right at the "dollar-one" placeholder and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to determine whether I'm missing something semantic here or whether this is is an actual Postgresql-core error which can be espoused by the code shown below.

```
-- Attempt to run the following on any database.
-- Creating the relations of the correct names etc. should not be necessary,
-- as the error occurs before this would even matter.

-- The code below fails in an unexpected way because no substitution appears
-- to take place.

--
-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
-- LINE 3:    special_constraint_trigger($1,$2,$3);
--                                       ^
-- SQL state: 42601
-- Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at EXECUTE statement
--

DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE
    -- simulated parameters:
    referencing_table TEXT = 'the_great_referencer';
    referencing_column TEXT = 'fk_field';
    referenced_column TEXT = 'measurement_id';
    -- :simulated parameters
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER maybe_throw_some_exceptions AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON measurement 
         DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
         special_constraint_trigger($1,$2,$3);'
        USING referenced_column,referencing_table, referencing_column;
END;
$$;
```

Is it clear to anyone else why this `USING` substitution is not working? I would expect the above to simply break on the fact there are bogus tables and columns being referenced here, but on my system, Postgres seems to be more concerned about the un-replaced dollar-sign. Especially if others are able to reproduce this error, I will plan to file this as a bug.

**Version info**: PostgreSQL 9.2.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

**OS**: Linux 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 24 01:31:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should not work - the params can be used only with SQL statement with a plan. DML (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) and `SELECT` are statements with the plan. DDL statements has not plan, and then should not be parametrized. So you cannot to use clause `USING` for any DDL statements like `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`. You have to execute some SQL string without any parameters - following code should to work:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER maybe_throw_some_exceptions
                   AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON measurement 
                   DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
                   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
                   special_constraint_trigger(%I,%I,%I)',
                  referenced_column,
                  referencing_table,
                  referencing_column);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Intuitively, the original code I provided should *ideally* fail with an *explicit* error stating that `USING` is not compatible with `CREATE` statements, don't you think? That is, there is a case for submitting this as a bug because the exception's error-text is vague?

Comment: The message is pretty correct, but you need the knowleadge about PLpgSQL internals to understand. So this is not bug, although the error message is not intuitive.  But I don't know, how much work it can need, and if there isn't some trap and potential compatibility break.